# How to install the latest version of KDE Plasma on the latest version of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, plasma, kde5

Right now I'm using Kubuntu 17.10 which ships with KDE 5.10. I'd like to get the most recent version of KDE though, which right now is KDE 5.11. Is there a way to automatically get the latest version of KDE without having to wait for the next Ubuntu release? I haven't been able to find a PPA or at least a standalone package.
I'm looking for as neat and simple a way as possible, so compiling from source or installing manually is out of the question in this case.

Thank you in advance for any hints you might be able to provide.

Comment: It should be in the _neon_ PPA I would think.

Comment: The neon PPA doesn't work for 18.04 yet. Any other ways?

Comment: Exercise your patience and wait? Shipping newer KDE/Qt onto a stable Ubuntu is not a trivial task. Or get involved in the community and help get things tested and working. 18.04 already ships with KDE 5.12 though.